# The code coloring in emacs22 on Mac OS X is rather weak. Is there any way I can grab Ubuntu's emacs configs?

Tags: macos, emacs, ubuntu

I don't at all like the default colorings on Mac OS X, but I love them on Ubuntu. What config files govern these things? I'm hoping I can just copy the relevant files from Ubuntu onto Mac OS X.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get color-theme.el

- http://nongnu.org/color-theme/

The color themes which are included aren't as nice as the TextMate themes, however you can now generate random color themes using Sweyla's web based code color generator...

- http://inspiration.sweyla.com/code/

I've modified a web based theme editor to allow you to edit an existing theme.

- http://jasonm23.github.com/emacs-theme-editor/
- example themes here: http://jasonm23.github.com/

(the original editor for reference and props - http://alexpogosyan.com/color-theme-creator/ )

Google for TextMate theme emacs and you can also find, Midnight and Blackboard converted to Emacs color-themes.

(Updated: added proper links for other tools.)

Answer (score 1):

I'm running emacs 24 out of homebrew.  Is emacs 22 important to you?  It's quite old.

Comment: Concerning that, I don't know how to build emacs without X support, and since I prefer to use it in the terminal, I'm stuck with what I have. Do you know how to build it with nox?

Comment: brew install --cocoa --HEAD --use-git-head emacs

Comment: Assuming you have the dev libraries available to build it with X support, then you can use `emacs -nw` to run it in the terminal, and `alias emacs='emacs -nw'` in your shell profile to make that default behaviour.

Answer (score -3):

You could also try TextMate (http://macromates.com/) - it's the absolute best editor out there.

Comment: I migrated from TextMate to emacs a while back.  Two major versions of emacs have come out with features I use -- many of which you simply can't do in TM.  Your opinion is unrelated to this question, though.

Comment: I have to agree, I also moved from TextMate to Emacs. Out the box, Emacs can appear to be a lesser beast than TextMate, but if your aim is to create a more TextMate like editor from Emacs, it's pretty easy... however, to create a more Emacs like editor from TextMate... is impossible.